# Generate PHP script for HTML form

Tags: php, forms

To preface, I am sorry for asking what is likely an extremely simple question. I am an intern for a non-profit helping with some web tasks and have been asked to build a submission form. I want the data inputted in the fields to send to my email address. The form code is fine, however it is the PHP script that seems to not be working. Can anyone suggest a simple PHP code (or another method) to parse this info a designated email address? Currently using method="post"

Here is the form code: http://pastebin.com/7Gxb92n5

Thank you!

Alex

Comment: I see no PHP code in there. What's your error exactly?

Comment: Hi Mario- here's the PHP. The data is not sending to my email. Wondering where I am getting it wrong, as the fields should be stored and email body string is created. http://pastebin.com/duXxnJCy

Comment: Remove the `@` in front of `@mail(` and see if it gives any clues. Most likely a processing or server configuration error. Also `$email_from` is undefined, and would need better preparation than your `clean_string()`.

Comment: @Alex Just in case... the email is going to webmaster@marineconomicforum.org is that you?

Comment: @Mario, thank you I will give that a try. @Akinator, yes that is me, i wish that was the problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form uses the method POST, so in send_form_application.php you will have to use the [mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

```
Name [Last, First MI] <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
Primary Organization <input type="text" name="primary_organization" /><br />
```

This above is your HTML that will POST variables contained in a $_POST array.

So `$_POST['name']` will contain you name and
`$_POST['primary_organization']` will contain the primary organization (what the user made as an input in the form)

The "most important part" of this HTML input is the `name` because it is what you will use to "fill" the mail function with it's attributes.

Your PHP will look something like:

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

The `$content` could be all the elements of the post like this (should actually be above the previous code)

$content = $_POST['name'] . "\n";
$content .= $_POST['primary_organization'] . "\n";

?>

And so on...

Please tell me if you cant understand something!

IMPORTANT: while this might work, this is not really secure yet, you should ALWASY validate the user input!

Comment: Ok sorry this was before I saw toy posted the PHP code, I'll leave it there because it may help you... don't know. I'll take a look ant the PHP now.

Comment: Any chance it is possible to create a script that would send the form without having to get/post each value first, ie: everything between <form> and </form>?

Comment: @Alex if I understood your question correctly, the answer would be NO, sorry :)

Comment: Ah, nothing comes easy. :) Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Please no problem at all!! tell me if you need any further explanation!! and yes, some things you just have to do them!! Good luck!!

Comment: Akinator, I've followed your instructions above, but am getting the following error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\www\mo\marinecforum\send_form_application.php on line 53

Comment: Akinator, I've followed your instructions above, but am getting the following error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\www\mo\marinecforum\send_form_application.php on line 53 Wondering if you may know the problem? Here is the PHP:http://pastebin.com/UKQ99GFV. Thank you!

Comment: @Alex that is a very specific error, you probably missed a ";" or something like that, go to line 53 (and 52, 51, and 50) and check it CERY closely, there sometimes very hard to find but one mistake and your code work work at all. I can't help you any further without the actual code, there simply too many possibilities. If you can't fix it, please open ask in another question because it's a whole different topic. If you want after asking the question you may post you link here in the comments and I gladly try to help. Good luck!! :)

Comment: Oh, now I see you've added the code, I'll take a look, but it still stands, if you don't post a question, it's just me helping, if you do, it's the whole community! :)

Comment: You got it wrong it is not `$content =$_POST['name'];. "\n";` it is:  `$content =$_POST['name'] . "\n";` on ALL of them!!

Comment: BTW: Depends ont your system but you might need: "\r\n" instead of "\n" too.

Comment: I have to leave for a while now, I'll be back in less than an hour but start by correcting your first problem and from there we'll see! Good lupck!

Comment: Awesome, again thank you. I've posted a new question. Upon fixing that issue, there is a new syntax error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\www\mo\marinecforum\send_form_application.php on line 90.) I think I am dealing with a domino effect, fix one error, one more springs up. :)

Answer (score 1):

On the .php page handling the post ("send_form_application.php" in your case),handle all incoming form fields in the following way:

1) Create variables to store each of your incoming form fields...
...

```
$name = $_POST["name"]
$primary_org = $_POST["primary_organization"]
$primary_pos = $_POST["primary_position"]
```

..
ETC...

2) Create an email body string variable to hold all these values however you want to...

3) Then use php's mail functionality to email the info to yourself...
More info here-> http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

To verify your server/mail configuration is okay, try the simplest possible code:

```
<?php
    mail("info@nonprofit.org", "form info", print_r($_POST, TRUE));
```

And you could assemble the body much easier like this (note that clean_string makes no sense for the email body):

```
$email_message = <<<END
   Name [Last, First MI] : $_POST["name..."]
   Primary Organization : $_POST["org..."]
   Street Address : $_POST["street..."]
   City : $_POST["city..."]
   State : $_POST["state..."]
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well here is a script that should give you the basic Idea on how to send an email via PHP
http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/How_to_Send_Email_from_a_PHP_Script.htm

But other than that your html looks fine...